# Почему указатель прыгает в цикле?

Tags: строки, c++

Вообщем не могу понять почему указатель прыгает в цикле, и если вывести итое в начале и в конце оно будет отличаться.

```
char str[100];
gets_s(str);

for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
    if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        if(str[i+1] >= '0' && str[i+1] <= '9')
            if(str[i+2] < '0' || str[i+2] > '9')
                puts(str);
```

Ну тут типо вывод строки на экран если в ней есть двузначное число. Работает естественно не так как надо и идея уг, но не в этом суть вопроса (суть наверху).

Comment: что-то ничего не прыгает. что за с++ такой ?

Comment: @VladD, да я же акцентировал внимание на том, что не в коде вопрос. Это все очевидные вещи, но код и без того уг. Вот если перед первым ифом вывести str[i] и там вместе в puts, то они разные. Вот что я не могу понять. И я говорю про одну итерацию

Comment: @VladD ну просил же а... Я знаком с азами спасибо. Может я и правда где-то сам ошибся, а теперь спрашиваю сам не зная чего, но азы меня не интересуют, которыми закидали прям сразу.

Comment: `Я знаком с азами спасибо` 

самое страшное - это врать самому себе. Так вы ничего не добьетесь.
Почему вы не знаете азов?. 

Первое:
`не могу понять почему указатель прыгает в цикле` - хотя не про какие указатели здесь речи не идет (хотя к этому я уже придирался в своем ответе) :)

Второе:
`ведь имя массива это указатель на первый символ` - это вообще что такое? Это очень далеко от реальности.

Третье:

`Вообщем я понял, что не объяснить это виртуально походу` - не умение задать вопрос говорит об ограниченности знаний хотя бы в той области по которой вы задаете вопрос.

Comment: Я не в коем случае не хочу вас обидеть. И я прошу прощения если, вдруг, я вас все таки обидел. Просто вы пришли тут и говорите всем что вы классный и знаете азы а на самом деле это не так. 

Здесь всем по сути дела все равно, знаете вы азы или нет. 

Самое обидное, по крайней мере, для меня то, что вы врете. Я вот не люблю когда мне врут.

Comment: @RubyNub: вы ж можете легко проверить вашу гипотезу насчёт индекса.
Попробуйте намного модифицированный цикл:

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
    {
        cout << "iteration start " << i << endl;
        if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
            if(str[i+1] >= '0' && str[i+1] <= '9')
                if(str[i+2] < '0' || str[i+2] > '9')
                    puts(str);
        cout << "iteration end " << i << endl;
    }

Вы сможете легко проконтролировать значения `i`.

Comment: @KryDos ну вообщем я сюда не выпендриваться зашел. Просто получилась такая ситуация, что я скорее всего вывел значение разных элементов и было это на другом компьютере, и вот придя к своему я как-то совсем по глупости ничего не проверив кинулся задавать вопрос. Вот и напоролся на вашу критику) Ну с++ меня лишь для института интересует, по этому не спорю знания мои там на низком уровне. Вообщем извините, я понял, что зря поспешил.

Answer (score 2):

С трудом понял вопрос из-за того, что у вас тут нигде не используются указатели. То о чем вы говорите называется индекс или может быть еще как-то это можно назвать но не "**указатель**", потому что в **С** и **C++** есть понятие указатель и оно обозначает совсем другое.

Далее. Вы используете цикл, в котором переменная **i** инкрементируется(увеличивается на один) каждый раз при новой итерации цикла. Соответственно то **i** что было в начале будет отличатся от того **i** что будет в конце.

[Есть несколько типов циклов](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html). И если вам не нужно, чтобы каждый раз при итерации увеличивалась **i** то используйте, например, цикл [while](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) и просто ничего не делайте с **i** (в смысле не увеличивайте).

Ну и вообще, в таком случае говорят "**[Учите мат.часть](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)**".

Comment: всё-таки не смог я суть вопроса донести
Я имел ввиду не последнюю итерацию, а именно начало и конец тела цикла. Ну вы не придерайтесь уж так, ведь имя массива это указатель на первый символ вот я и выразился так

Comment: @RubyNub, попробуйте еще раз ;)

Comment: и в начале и в конце цикла i одинаково. у тебя просто с++ неправильный :)

Comment: Но этот код выведет строку, если там трехзначное число - два раза. То есть если в строке есть трехзначное число, то он эту строку два раза выведет, а не должен.

Comment: input: 1234
processing...
output: 1234
end

что я делаю не так?

Comment: @afiki ну вот не должен он этого выводить, число то четырехзначное. Вообщем я понял, что не объяснить это виртуально походу... Ну вот выведите str[i] перед первым if и в теле последнего(именно значение).

Comment: input: 1234
output: str[i] before = 49
str[i] before = 50
str[i] before = 51
str[i] after = 51
1234
str[i] before = 52
end

как можно заметить, попадание всего одно и значения одинаковы.

Comment: @RubyNub, сделайте в начале и в конце цикла 

`printf ("%d", i);`

и убедитесь в том что i не изменяется.

Comment: @RubyNub: То есть вы утверждаете, что в процессе вычисления if'ов странным образом поменялось значение `i`? Не _между_ итерациями цикла, а в пределах _одной_ итерации?

Comment: @VladD ну из ваших слов я утверждаю полный абсурд. Вообщем в комментарии к вопросу всё объяснил. Из-за не знания с++ и боязни чего-то упустить я кинулся задавать вопрос, даже не углубляясь, вот и вышла тут беседа по азам и критике в мою сторону. Бывает вообщем.

Comment: @RubyNub: не-не, это не критика. Просто мы пытаемся выяснить, что именно не так. Вы и правда немного плаваете в этой тематике, поэтому нам приходится выспрашивать точную проблему.

Если вы сумеете нам объяснить проблему, может быть, мы сможем вам помочь. Постараетесь?